# ASP.NET Custom Validator Client side & Server Side validation not firing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

This has not happened to me before, but for some reason both the client and server side validation events are not being triggered:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDTownCity" runat="server" CssClass="contactfield" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true"
    ErrorMessage="Delivery Town or City required"
    ClientValidationFunction="TextBoxDTownCityClient" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxDTownCity"
    OnServerValidate="TextBoxDTownCity_Validate" Display="Dynamic" >
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Server-side validation event:

```
protected void TextBoxDTownCity_Validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Client-side validation event:

```
function TextBoxDCountyClient(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = false;
    alert("test");
}
```

I thought at the least the Server Side validation would fire but no.  this has never happened to me before.  This has really got me stumped.

I looked at the output and ASP.NET is recognizing the client side function:

ASP.NET JavaScript output:

```
var ctl00_ctl00_content_content_CustomValidator2 = document.all ? document.all["ctl00_ctl00_content_content_CustomValidator2"] : document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_content_content_CustomValidator2");

ctl00_ctl00_content_content_CustomValidator2.controltovalidate = "ctl00_ctl00_content_content_TextBoxDTownCity";

ctl00_ctl00_content_content_CustomValidator2.errormessage = "Delivery Town or City required";

ctl00_ctl00_content_content_CustomValidator2.display = "Dynamic";

ctl00_ctl00_content_content_CustomValidator2.evaluationfunction = "CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid";

ctl00_ctl00_content_content_CustomValidator2.clientvalidationfunction = "TextBoxDTownCityClient";
```

Rendered custom validator:

```
<span id="ctl00_ctl00_content_content_CustomValidator2" style="color:Red;display:none;">Delivery Town or City required</span>
```

Can any one shed some light as to why both client and server side validation would not be firing.

**Edit: Typo I pasted in the wrong function, problem still the same**

Just another update to the last comment: where by the TextBox cannot be empty.  I tested this out and it is not true.  On a blank page the CustomValidator fired my client side validation function fine without a value:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ClientValidationFunction="TextBoxDAddress1Client"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Your `CustomValidator` will only fire when the `TextBox` isn't empty.

If you need to ensure that it's not empty then you'll need a [`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) too.

> [**Note:** If the input control is empty,
>   no validation functions are called and
>   validation succeeds. Use a
>   RequiredFieldValidator control to
>   require the user to enter data in the
>   input control.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx)

**EDIT:**

If your `CustomValidator` specifies the `ControlToValidate` attribute (and your original example does) then your validation functions will only be called when the control isn't empty.

If you don't specify `ControlToValidate` then your validation functions will be called every time.

This opens up a second possible solution to the problem. Rather than using a separate `RequiredFieldValidator`, you could omit the `ControlToValidate` attribute from the `CustomValidator` and setup your validation functions to do something like this:

Client Side code (Javascript):

```
function TextBoxDCountyClient(sender, args) {
    var v = document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxDTownCity.ClientID%>').value;
    if (v == '') {
        args.IsValid = false;  // field is empty
    }
    else {
        // do your other validation tests here...
    }
}
```

Server side code (C#):

```
protected void TextBoxDTownCity_Validate(
    object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string v = TextBoxDTownCity.Text;
    if (v == string.Empty)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;  // field is empty
    }
    else
    {
        // do your other validation tests here...
    }
}
```

Comment: too quick for me, I was typing same answer :) +1

Comment: "Your CustomValidator will only fire when the TextBox isn't empty"  I tested this on a clean page and it is not true.  The client validation function fires even when the textbox is empty

Comment: My bad.  I see what i need to do.  If I omit the ControlToValidate property then I succeed in what I want to do, and the client side function fires when I need.

Comment: This is a cool fix and worked for me.  However, I use the ValidatorCalloutExtender from the Ajax Control Toolkit and it requires the ControlToValidate property to be set.  It's always something...  :-(

Comment: Dont forget to specify your javascript script tag correctly, otherwise the validation method is not triggered. (Only if you use an ugly javascript block in your ASPX file.) 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

Comment: You could also use the CustomValidator.ValidateEmptyText Property?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 137):

Use this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="vld" ValidateEmptyText="true"/>
```

To validate an empty field.

You don't need to add 2 validators !

Comment: The solution i was searching for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Client-side validation was not being executed at all on my web form and I had no idea why.  It turns out the problem was the name of the javascript function was the same as the server control ID.

So you can't do this...

```
<script>
  function vld(sender, args) { args.IsValid = true; }
</script>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="vld" ClientValidationFunction="vld" />
```

But this works:

```
<script>
  function validate_vld(sender, args) { args.IsValid = true; }
</script>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="vld" ClientValidationFunction="validate_vld" />
```

I'm guessing it conflicts with internal .NET Javascript?

Answer (score 4):

Also check that you are not using validation groups as that validation wouldnt fire if the validationgroup property was set and not explicitly called via

```
 Page.Validate({Insert validation group name here});
```

Comment: Yes, but you still need text in the textbox for the validator to work anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Did you verify that the control causing the post back has CausesValidation set to tru and that it does not have a validation group assigned to it?

I'm not sure what else might cause this behavior.

Comment: I use an ImageButton for the Submit, and I have not stated any validation group.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side validation won't fire if client-side validation is invalid, the postback is not send.

Don't you have some other validation that doesn't pass?

The client-side validation is not executed because you specified `ClientValidationFunction="TextBoxDTownCityClient"` and this will look for a function named `TextBoxDTownCityClient` as validation function, but the function name should be
`TextBoxDAddress1Client`

(as you wrote)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that info on the ControlToValidate LukeH!

What I was trying to do in my code was to only ensure that some text field A has some text in the field when text field B has a particular value. Otherwise, A can be blank or whatever else. Getting rid of the ControlToValidate="A" in my mark up fixed the issue for me.

Cheers!