# Compare validation for two custom control

Tags: asp.net, validation, c#-3.0

I have scenario, Page contains Check in date and Check out date for input. I used user control for datepicker, so both dates are called same user control. 
Like,

Check In Date: `<uc:datepicker ID="CheckInDate" runat="server" />`
 Check Out Date: `<uc:datepicker ID="CheckOutDate" runat="server" />`

Now I do validation for both dates which should not be blank like.

```
public class CustomiseDatePickerValidator : BaseValidator
 {

   protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
        {
            Control c = this.FindControl(this.ControlToValidate);
            DatePicker datepickerSelected = c as DatePicker;
            ICustomiseRadDatePicker additionUserControl =    (ICustomiseRadDatePicker)c.Parent;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(datepickerSelected.DateInput.Text))
             {
                return false;
             }

            return true;
        }
 }
```

This is working fine but I want also compare both datepicker value So Check in date Should be less than Check out date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be easier to use a `CustomValidator` for this. With the `CustomValidator`, you can specify your own client-side validation logic.

See this question for more details:
[ASP.NET Custom Validator Client side & Server Side validation not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701029/asp-net-custom-validator-client-side-server-side-validation-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but i think you need to use a CompareValidator for this. Correct me if i am missing something

Comment: I know that but I have to validate two datepicker which are inside the user control.

Comment: OK,i get you, actualy you can use a hack for using validation controls for Usercontrols, i mean the validation controls are not within the UserControl, just try setting ControlToValidate="uc1:TextBox1",  where TextBox1 is the name of the server control you want to validate thats within the UserControl. I have got this to work successfully for RequiredValidator on a Textbox within a UserControl. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to a CustomValidator is to  apply the ValidationPropertyAttribute to the user control class.  That way you can use normal ASP.NET validators against the user control as you would any other control.