# Only one letter in text box validation

Tags: c#, html, .net

Can someone tell my what I need to put in the text box required field validator to read just the first initial of one word? Also, if the user puts more than one letter, to show him the validation error in the label.

```
 <div class="form-group" style="width:350px">                  
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name (required)" id="inputdefault1" type="text"/>
                   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server"  ValidationGroup="NewStudent" ControlToValidate="inputdefault1" ErrorMessage="Please enter your name" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group" style="width:350px">
                   <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Initial (required)" id="InitialId" type="text"/>
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ValidationGroup="NewStudent" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}" ControlToValidate="InitialId" ErrorMessage="Please enter your last initial"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
               </div>
```

The first text box is the place where the name should be put in, and the second text box is where the initial should be put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [Custom Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701029/asp-net-custom-validator-client-side-server-side-validation-not-firing).

You can then write the Javascript and your C# to handle the Client side and Server side validation (respectively).

You can just check to see if the length of the field is 1, and that it's not a space.  That would probably be the quickest logic.