# How to call JavaScript function when ASP.Net validators succeed?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a webform with ASP.Net controls and Validators for them setup into a group. I am trying to execute some JavaScript that occurs only when the validators succeed, to prevent the user from going onto the next step of the form without completing the requirements.

However, I cannot seem to get this to work properly. The JavaScript either executes without validation completing, or the JavaScript won't execute when validated successfully. I have a sneaking suspicion that this is due to the combination of HTML `Required="true"` tags, and ASP.Net validators behaving differently.

**ASP.Net**

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailAddress" runat="server" TextMode="Email" Required="true" ValidationGroup="Group1" />

<asp:TextBox ID="Password1" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Required="true" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password1" 
    ErrorMessage="Your password doesn't meet the strength requirements" 
    ValidationExpression="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[/W_].*)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,255}" 
    ValidationGroup="Group1" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="Password2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Required="true" ValidationGroup="Group1" 
/>
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password1" ControlToValidate="Password2"  
    ErrorMessage="Your entered passwords do not match." ValidationGroup="Group1" />

<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text=">" OnClientClick="pgNext();" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function pgNext() {
    if (Page_ClientValidate("Group1")) {
        $('.register-page1').css('display', 'none');
        $('.register-page2').css('display', 'block');
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Create a `CustomValidator`

Comment: Why not use validation group instead? If the goal is to prevent an action when it is not yet valid to go to the next step?

Comment: @tontonsevilla I have a validation group in the code `ValidationGroup="Group1"` - is this what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @VDWWD - do you mind expanding on how I would do so? Thank you

Comment: https://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/. It's very simple, just return `e.IsValid = true;` when all your own checks have completed.

Comment: Thanks @VDWWD - so once this Server Side validation completes in the CodeBehind, I assume I can then call Page_IsValid in the JS, or is this a complete ServerSide solution?

Comment: This is client side validation. Server side also requires custom code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701029/asp-net-custom-validator-client-side-server-side-validation-not-firing

Comment: Thank you @VDWWD - I understand the `CustomValidator` part, I'm struggling with how I can call the javascript function when validated from this? Thanks

Comment: Here is a better demo. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction?view=netframework-4.8. You put your own javascript here `if (arguments.Value % 2 == 0 ){ CUSTOMCODE(); arguments.IsValid = true; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your page validator, then check if page is valid, then finally call your js function.
In your button  click event:

```
 Page.Validate("validationGroupNameHere");

 if(Page.IsValid)
 {
   // click code here
   
  //then call your js function
  Page.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "callMe", " jsFunctionNameHere();", true);
 }
```